# Cycle animation background issue

Tags: objective-c

CABasicAnimation enter foreground(repeatCount = 5). Add animation again, this animation will run twice. If not, this animation will not disappear when done and don't carry out animationDidStop.

Comment: Are you talking to yourself?

Answer (score 0):

However, a month has passed.Like the reply above, i answered myself! Briefly, every 5 seconds, the number of cycles is decremented by one, by using NSTimer.